# How to break Android OS security and root a phone, manually?

Tags: rooting, root-access, security

Not only that one click applications don't work on my phone, I want to DIY root my phone. Upon googling for quite some time, I couldn't find any updated guide. I am willing to write one myself, but please point me in the right direction. All I get when I google are either noob rooting guides or outdated information. What should I look for? How do I root the linux box?

If it matters, I have a Lenovo P780(Android Version : 4.4.2), and my PC runs both Ubuntu 14.014 and Arch Linux. I have adb and fastboot installed. I didnot manually install any phone drivers. Firstly I tried unlocking the bootloader by rebooting the phone into fastboot mode and trying a `sudo fastboot oem unlock`. The program doesn't do anything. No output.

Since my phone is MTK based ([MT6589](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=cpu&id=a6589&c=mediatek_mt6589)), I've tried Framaroot, but it fails with error #9. I remember that in the past when it had stock jellybean, the app worked, but after subsequent updates and upgrade to KitKat, not only did I loose root, but also the exploits might have got patched.

Comment: You didn't supplied any information about current android version running on your phone. I think you've updated from 4.2 to something new? Don't tell simple "nob rooting guides or outdated information" if you have updated to 4.4.x. What "one click root" have you tried anyway.

Comment: @user3344236 I've updated the question, even though I am more interested in the approach to rooting devices than rooting theparticular device.

Answer (score -2):

To root your phone you dont have to unlock it.

You could just download and flash a pre-rooted ROM for your phone.

Just google the correct zip file for your device (wrong device will brick your phone).

Then set phone to enter fastboot mode, and do:

```
fastboot devices
fastboot update theprerootrom.zip
fastboot reboot
```

Or set phone to debug mode, enter recovery, allow ADB, then do:

```
adb devices
adb sideload theprerootrom.zip
adb reboot
```

Comment: That's **blatantly wrong**. To install a pre-rooted ROM (which is never a stock) you need a custom recovery, which in order to install requires an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: iBug is wrong. Custom recovery purpose is to make recovery easier. Its not mandatory to root a phone which is the question.
It is true that some phone is locked for rooting, but not all.
In order to root a phone you don't have to break Android security. 
We're talking in general, not a specific smartphone.

Comment: There are STOCK ROOTED ROM, CUSTOM ROOTED ROM, and CUSTOM UNROOTED ROM. Custom ROM requires unlock, while stock ROM doesn't. Most unrooted ROM don't breaks Android security.
Custom recovery purpose is to do recovery, it can be used to write ROM's. ROM can be change without custom recovery: either with stock recovery, or with ROM writing function (fastboot / sideload).